# TFS Labels Command line

Tags: tfs, tf-cli, tfvc

I am trying to do the below using TFS command line TF.exe

1. Create and Apply label to latest version of files and subfolders under a folder
2. Compare 2 labels to find out difference between 2 labels, file names,changeset details etc

Both I'm trying to achieve through Command line

Comment: Below is what I tried ...tf.exe label TEST1 /version:T /comment:Testing /recursive /collection:XXXX05\XXXdefaultcollection
 TF14064: Could not find label TEST1.

Comment: Also I see "TFS Label Diff.exe" to get diff between 2 labels

Answer (score 4):

To create a label:

> ```
> tf label "LabelName" /owner:domain\me $/Project /version:T /recursive
> ```

You need to specify the root path of your label. Which seems to be missing from your example.

For differences between two labels use:

> ```
> tf diff "$/Project/Path;LlabelnameA" "$/Project/Path;LlabelnameB" /recursive /noprompt
> ```
>
> Note that the `;...` part instructs to take the Itemspec at a specific version `;L...` tells it to look up the version by label. Insert the label name on the `...`

Then for each file that's returned you can dig deeper.